# Does UTF-16 have some kind of separator in it?

Tags: utf-8

From the UTF-16's [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), the second sentence states it's a variable length encoding.

But where is the separator between a 16-bit character and 32-bit encoding? I know a lot of characters can be stored in the 16-bit character, so people can optimize UTF-6 that way, but I'm still curious because there could come a time when we could surpass the 16-bit mark.

And no worries, I know UTF-8 is standard. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you're asking for the mechanism that allows UTF-16 to represent 32-bit characters, which is called [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF). That Wikipedia article pretty thoroughly explains it.

Incidentally, we surpassed 16 bits a long time ago. In fact, the main reason UTF-16 is widely used is that the fixed-length UCS-2 encoding became popular back when people thought 16 bits would be enough, then it wasn't, so UTF-16 is the easy-to-port-to option for everyone who started using UCS-2.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. Sorry, the tutorials about UTF I was reading didn't cover that.

Answer (score 4):

It's a very similar principle to UTF-8. In UTF-8, you can look at a single byte and it is either a "single byte code point", "first of two bytes", "first of three bytes", "first of four bytes" or "continuation of two, three or four byte code point".

In UTF-16, you can look at a single 16 bit value, and it is either a "single 16-bit word code point", or "first of two halves" or "second of two halves": The codes D800 to DBFF are "first halves", the codes DC00 to DCFF are "second halves", and to get a 32 bit code point you combine the last ten bits of each, giving a 20 bit value, and add 0x10000.